# How to create a single form in Access with 10+ tables

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a single form in access to input data into 15 tables in the relational database but Access keeps shutting down when I try to. The total number of fields in the database is over 60. How do I create a single form capable of inputting data into all these tables?

I’ve tried using Tab control and page break to create multiple pages but they don’t seem to help. The database still shuts down

Answer (score 0):

According to [Access specifications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c#projects) the number of controls in a form is limited.

> Number of controls and sections you can add over the lifetime of the form or report: 754

What you can do is to use subforms to reduce the number of controls in the main form.

See: [Create a form that contains a subform (a one-to-many form)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b)

Instead of binding the subform to a details table you would bind it to the main table and thus create a one-to-one relationship.

Or instead of working with individual controls for each field, use the sub-forms in the datasheet view. They will then display as a grid, where you can enter the data.